# Is that possible to use map object ( PHP_MapScript ) instead of map file when using the MapServer?

Tags: mapserver, php, mapscript

In my previous code, I am using OpenLayers WMS to load a raster data through MapServer. As you can see, the mapserv.exe calls a local map file to load the raster data. I just heard PHP_MapScript, since it can convert a map file into a map object.

Is that possible to use this converted map object directly in OpenLayers WMS? Since the object can be easily modified such as "styling".

```
localWMS = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Local WMS layers",
          "http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?MAP=C:/Users/mapserver.map",
          {layers: 'polygon',transparent: true}, {isBaseLayer: false} );
map.addLayer(localWMS);
```

Someone who is familiar with PHP_MapScript, I am willing to hear from you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **no**.

**Mapscript** and the **mapfile** are executed on the server and they have nothing to do with the **OpenLayers** client-side **JavaScript**. What you are requesting with **OpenLayers.Layer.WMS** is a set of images and metadata and by the time these get to the browser there is not much you can manipulate.
**Mapscript** can be useful if you need to do lots of dynamic or repetitive manipulations on the server side, before the image is generated.

Comment: Thanks. Is that mapscript something similar to openlayer since it has function $map = ms_newMapObj(""). All the tutorial are saying mapserver can publish a map directly using $map->draw() function. I am confused what kind of map it will draw or just an image file with url. And then show this image on website with src=url. Thank you.

Comment: $map->draw() will draw an image. You can save that image, print it or show it on a website as any other image... you know, a simple image, nothing more.

Comment: Hi Decio, I post a new question regarding the mapfile. Could you have a look in your convenience. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64284/how-to-add-a-legend-for-mapfile-raster-data