# How to add a legend for mapfile (Raster Data)

Tags: mapserver, mapfile

What I would like to do is shown in the figure below. How can I add this color ramp legend in a mapfile which will also be linked to a raster. I don't know how to get it working while drawing a figure based on that mapfile.

Thanks !

[image: ArcGIS]

Comment: Nice map! Why would you want to use a mapfile generated legend here? What you have looks fine.

Comment: What I am doing is to build an online web system which is for my Master Thesis. So I can't use ArcGIS.

Comment: Got it! No, I am not saying to use ArcGIS, use mapserver. I am only saying do not use mapserver to generate the legend, just do it in html and css and you will have nicer results.

Comment: It sounds interesting. Could you give me some clue or useful example? Thanks

Comment: Tell me something more! What is this for? A poster? A Web application? If it is for a Web application, what do you know and not know about Web development?

Comment: It's a web application. I know a little bit Java Script, a little bit PHP, a little bit OpenLayers. Actually this raster map will shown in openlayer.

Comment: OK, few tips. Use mapserver mapfile, not mapscript. If you can, look into something like [mapproxy](http://mapproxy.org/), read the docs and the examples. For your Web layout use something like [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) or similar and read about the scaffolding section. For the legend, create a space in your layout for it and put it there, it is just html with some css and an image. In general think first how your application is going to look, draw it, then try to implement the html and then wire up the js. Use time studying and trying, not asking pointless questions.

Comment: The thing why I am trying to use mapscript is the map should be dynamic. So every user can create their own map which means the legend will be updated accordingly. But thanks for your reply anyway. Only one thing I don't agree. I don't think there is pointless questions and the studying and asking can never be a conflict.

Comment: Did not mean to offend, but only point out that the question was completely out of context. Now, after all these comments, I have a better understanding of your problem, but this was in no way clear in the original question. I suggested not to use mapscript because in my experience is hard, inconsistent and slow and alternative approaches do exist... but this is just my personal opinion. Anyway, go to the docs, there is a mapscript method for almost every mapfile object, legend included. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Decio. The MapScript doesn't support "Color Range" function yet. I got that news from Developer mail list of mapserver.

Comment: So this question was asked 2 years ago, and wondering whether you found your solution.